# Selenium+Python открывает пустую страницу,не переходит по url

Tags: python, парсер, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Selenium не переходит по ссылке, открывает пустую страницу.Браузер chrome. Драйвер скачан,находится в папке с программой.Версия браузера совпадает с версией драйвера.Пробовал с Оперой,то же самое,открывает пустую страницу.Все показал на скринах.

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
from selenium import webdriver

def get_html(url):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(url)


def main():
    get_html('https://www.youtube.com/')

main()
```

[image: Версия браузера]
[image: Версия драйвера]

Comment: код, приведенный в вопросе, абсолютно работоспособен: запускает драйвер, открывает страницу youtube, закрывает драйвер

Comment: @Jack_oS но у меня почему то нет, открывается пустая страница.

Comment: решение было найдено?